# Abstract function qml

Tags: qt, oop, qml

i want to create an abstract class with abstract functions in QML in theory some thing like this:

```
//abstract.qml
QtObject{
     abstract function implementLater(var input);
}

Abstract{
     //and here i have to implement it
     function implementLater(var input){
         console.log(input)
     }
}
```

how can i do this in qml or maybe in c++ and register it to qml?

**update** :
here is what i'm trying to do, in my `uvaluemask` object i should have a function named `mask` which will be `abstract` and i call this for every child which will be different, you can call childs method directly i'm doing this right now and its working, but my component "UValueMask" is missing difinition for mask method,i mean i need to force users of UValueMask to define a `mask` method .

```
    //UValueMask.qml
    QtObject {
        property string name:""
    }
    //singleton Object
    UListObject{
        property UValueMask timeMask :UValueMask{
            id:timemask
            name: "time"
            function mask(input,splitter){
                return innerObj.convertIntToTime(input,splitter)
            }

        }
        property UValueMask dateMask: UValueMask{
            id:datemask
            name:"date"
            function mask(input,splitter){
                return innerObj.convertIntToDate(input,splitter)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot create abstract class, by definition. Just to avoid XY problem - what is your real target?

Comment: @MahdiKhalili QML does not implement all OOP features

Comment: there is some sort of abstraction in button https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-abstractbutton.html